# Missing parentheses in CREATE TABLE instruction

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE MAJEST_PROD_2015(
  PRODUCT_ID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION_PROD CHAR(30),
  SEW_DATE DATE,
  HARVEST_DATE DATE,
  QUANTITY INT,
  PROD_RATING INT(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID)
);
```

Error report -

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you. Also, questions which root causes are typographical errors are off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Oracle` is not `MySQL` so there is no `INT(1)` type:

```
CREATE TABLE MAJEST_PROD_2015(
   PRODUCT_ID CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   DESCRIPTION_PROD CHAR(30),
   SEW_DATE DATE,
   HARVEST_DATE DATE,
   QUANTITY INT,
   PROD_RATING INT,            -- here
   PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCT_ID) 
);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7286c)**</kbd>

If you don't need constant size of string, consider using `VARCHAR2(30)`.

**EDIT:**

> but i need those values to be between 1-5

So add check constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_PROD_RATING CHECK (PROD_RATING BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db419e)**</kbd>

Comment: but i need those values to be between 1-5... anyway thank you

Comment: @Maria `INT(1)` allows to insert 6,7,8,9 so it secures nothing. You need to use `CHECK` constraint or trigger.

Answer (score 1):

As [already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34875133/1509264) `INT` does not take a length constraint in Oracle - instead you could use `NUMBER(1,0)` which would restrict it to a single digit (`-9 .. +9`) and then you can further restrict it using a `CHECK` constraint.

`CHAR(n)` will also right pad the value with space (`CHR(32)`) characters so that it always contains the maximum number of characters. If you did not intend this then you should be using `VARCHAR2(n)` instead.

You also do not need a `NOT NULL` constraint on a column that is the `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
CREATE TABLE MAJEST_PROD_2015(
  PRODUCT_ID       VARCHAR2(10)  CONSTRAINT MAJEST_PROD_2015__PROD_ID__PK PRIMARY KEY,
  DESCRIPTION_PROD VARCHAR2(30),
  SEW_DATE         DATE,
  HARVEST_DATE     DATE,
  QUANTITY         INT,
  PROD_RATING      NUMBER(1,0)   CONSTRAINT MAJEST_PROD_2015__PROD_RAT__CK CHECK ( PROD_RATING BETWEEN 1 AND 5 )
);
```

*(also, should it be `SEW_DATE` or `SOW_DATE`? Since the next line talks about harvest then I would have thought "sow" was more apt.)*